# Windows EADDRINUSE for every port (node.js)

Tags: node.js, http, httpserver

I'm trying to start a really simple http server, however every time I do `.listen(x)` it gives me `EADDRINUSE`. I've seen this error before, I know what it means and typically how to fix it. But for some reason nothing I've tried has worked. It's worth noting this code works just fine on my linux server.

Here's the code:

```
const http = require("http")
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200)
    return res.end()
}).listen(8888)
```

Like I said, super simple, yet no port works. Here's what I've tried:

- netstat
- computer restart
- looping over ports [1000, 9999] (all returned eaddrinuse)
- adding a host ("0.0.0.0", but it node defaults it anyways)

Here's the console for the loop, but it's just what is expected:
[image: loop]

I don't know what to do, obviously ports 1000-9999 aren't in use and something else is going on. `netstat` does not show any of these ports.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have WSL in use? Or Hyper-V? Run `netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` from a cmd.exe with administrative rights to check reserved ports. Try also running your program with administrative rights - could be some sort of a permissions issue (check the Event Viewer - could be traces there).

Comment: Considering I don't know what hyper-v is, I doubt it or WSL is in use (I don't even have wsl enabled). I have 5 excluded ports, yet none are the ones I'm using. I tried running it as admin (from a command prompt ran as admin) didn't work. And I don't see anything in event viewer.

Comment: Did the command I suggested reveal anything? Are you using a VPN? Internet Connection Sharing? A third party firewall? An overly-aggressive antivirus software?

Comment: I just noticed the "Cluster 0" message - what are you using to run Node? Just `node index.js`?

Comment: Yeah, that's because it's attached to a discord bot. But this is the only http server I open.

Comment: Please include the rest of the application.

Comment: The application spans across 20 files. Regardless I solved it. It did have to do with the whole cluster thing, I accidentally put it in the wrong file that gets required multiple times. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Great! I would recommend mentioning such details and context in the question since clusters certainly elevate the app beyond a super simple node app.